# Sorting a Python Dictionary that counts occurances of word by Ascending Key and Descending Value

Tags: python

Doing a programming exercise where I have to write a program that takes an input and prints a list of unique words contained in the strong with the number of occurrences of each word in the string. The list should be sorted in descending order by frequency, and ascending order alphabetically when multiple words occur with the same frequency.

Sample input: “This is a test. That is not a test. Test”
Output:

```
test 3
a 2
is 2
not 1
that 1
this 1
```

I tried doing this in Python3 with the following code but cant seem to get the order of keys right. Any help would be appreciated:

```
import operator
import re

a = 'This is a test. That is not a test. Test'
b = re.split('[\s,.;!?]', a.lower())

words = {}

for i in b:
    if i is not '':
        if i not in words:
            words[i] = 1
        else:
            words.update({i: words.get(i) + 1})

for key, value in sorted(words.items(), key = lambda kv: kv[1], reverse = True):
    print(key, value)
```

Output:

```
test 3                                                                                      
is 2                                                                                        
a 2                                                                                         
this 1                                                                                      
not 1                                                                                       
that 1
```

Comment: That results in:

`test 3                                                                                     
is 2                                                                                       
a 2                                                                                        
this 1                                                                                     
that 1                                                                                     
not 1`

Comment: Oh woops, my bad. Ignore that.

Comment: That's okay, do you have any other ideas on how to achieve the right solution?

Comment: You could remove the `reverse = True`, and try this key: `key = lambda kv: (-kv[1], len(kv[0]), kv[0])`. However, this only happens to work with this exact data. A better solution may be to just have a predefined order in which the key-value pairs should appear (such as a list of key-strings), and then iterate over the keys in the order in which they appear in that list.

Comment: How would I do that @PaulM.? I previously tried make a list of the dictionary values, sort them by descending order, then print out the dictionary key that corresponds to the value; but then the printed keys wouldn't necessarily be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Actually, never mind. The best solution of course would involve knowing just how the key-value pairs should be sorted. My suggested sorting scheme sorts by negative value, length of key, and then the key itself. This scheme happens to work for this data and those key-value pairs. You mentioned this was an exercise - for school I'm guessing? Maybe you can ask your instructor what the general order of the key-value pairs should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sort your array twice, by both elements. Sorting in python is guaranteed to be stable, so first you can sort by words and then by frequency. If frequency of two or more words is the same, then they will be sorted alphabetically. Also note that tuples are sorted by their first element by default and string is false in boolean context of and only if it's empty.

```
import re

a = 'This is a test. That is not a test. Test'
b = re.split('[\s,.;!?]', a.lower())

words = {}

for i in b:
    if i:
        words.update({i: words.get(i,0) + 1})

for key, value in sorted(sorted(words.items()), key = lambda kv: kv[1], reverse = True):
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a helpful class called Counter that can cut your work load.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

a = 'This is a test. That is not a test. Test'
counts = Counter(re.findall(r'[\w]+', a.lower()))
sort_func = lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])
for word, freq in sorted(counts.items(), key=sort_func):
    print(word, freq)
```

Longer code showing intermediate steps:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

a = 'This is a test. That is not a test. Test'
print(re.findall(r'\w+', a.lower()))
# ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'that', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'test', 'test']

counts = Counter(re.findall(r'[\w]+', a.lower()))
print(counts)
# Counter({'test': 3, 'is': 2, 'a': 2, 'this': 1, 'that': 1, 'not': 1})

print(counts.items())
# dict_items([('this', 1), ('is', 2), ('a', 2), ('test', 3), ('that', 1), ('not', 1)])

# Set up a sort function for the tuples above
sort_func = lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])
for word, freq in sorted(counts.items(), key=sort_func):
    print(word, freq)

test 3
a 2
is 2
not 1
that 1
this 1
```